# Delta MFCC Calculation

Tags: statistics, speech-recognition, mfcc

I'm currently experimenting with various feature vectors in order to maximise my speech recognition classification. I've read that using delta MFCC's and delta-delta MFCC's can improve the classification results.

My cross-validation test without delta's resulted 98% but decreased by 3% when using delta's.
Is the delta calculation for MFCC's can be done by simple difference operation?
Sharing my code below:

```
deltas = []
for x in xrange(n):
    delt = np.subtract(mfcc_feat[index+1],mfcc_feat[index])
    deltas.append(delt)
return np.array(deltas)

mfcc_delta = getDeltaMFCC(mfcc_normalised,0,13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't just take two adjacent feature frames to compute the delta, but perform a regression over multiple frames to come up with more stable deltas.

See [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/mfcc-deltas-delta-deltas) for a corresponding formula.